# Where are the Project's .py files located in virtualenvwrapper?

Tags: python, virtualenvwrapper

I installed virtualenvwrapper-win and successfully started a project. However, this project seems to be missing the standard project `*.py` files (`manage.py`, `urls.py` etc.)

In the virtual environment directory, I see the folders Include, Lib, Scripts and tcl. The project directory is empty. I cannot find the .py files necessary. For example: When running `python manage.py runserver`, the `manage.py` file cannot be found.

```
    (TestDjango) c:\Django\TestDjango>python manage.py runserver
    python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: did you install django after activating the virtualenv?

Comment: Yes, I did: 
`(TestDjango) c:\Django\TestDjango>pip freeze
Django==2.2.2
manage.py==0.2.10
pytz==2019.1
sqlparse==0.3.0`

Comment: This has nothing to do with virtualenvs or installed packages — the files simply aren't there. Are you sure you created the project correctly?

Comment: I used the virtualenvwrapper way, the `mkproject`. This creates the empty directory with the project name and at the same time virtual environment directory with aforementioned content

Comment: So apparently I answered myself, `mkproject` is not relevant to python or django project, it is virtualenv "project" and another django project has to be created inside. Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mkproject is not relevant to python or django project, it is virtualenv "project" and another django project has to be created inside, so logically no python files are available right after mkproject command